# PTAS vs. exact-time sub-exponential algorithms

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete

I have recently summarized several algorithms for the [maximum disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_disjoint_set) problem. This problem is NP-hard, but it has both PTAS and sub-exponential algorithms. These algorithms seem to me closely related. The details vary, but the general idea is:

- For a PTAS: remove a small fraction of the input set (e.g. $O(\sqrt{n})$ shapes). Partition the remaining input set to two subsets. Recursively find an approximate maximum set on each subset, and return the union of these two sets as the approximate solution.
- For a sub-exponential algorithm: instead of removing those $O(\sqrt{n})$ shapes, check all possible subsets of them. For each subset, do the recursive step as in the PTAS. Return the best solution found. The runtime is dominated by the number of all possible subsets, which is $O(2^\sqrt{n})$.

Initially I thought that maybe every problem with a PTAS has a sub-exponential exact algorithm, but I haven't found such a relation so I assume it is not true. My questions are therefore:

- Are there problems with PTAS but provably no subexponential algorithms (no algorithms with runtime $O(2^{n^e})$ with $e<1$)?
- Are there problems with subexponential algorithms but provably no PTAS?

Comment: When you say "provably", you mean "conditioned on the ETH" in the first point, and "unless P=NP" (at the very least) in the second point.

Comment: In the second point, he does not need anything like that. $\;$